# counting elements of various columns in laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel

I want to do a single count of two columns that I have in my database, if exists a record in one of the two columns I would like to take it in the count... In the two columns I have some elements that are repeated and I would like to take them in the same count.

I tried with this but it dind't work

```
$individuales = DB::table('incidencias')
    ->where('inc_padre', '!=', '')
    ->orWhere('nro_ticket' '!=', '')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(inc_padre), DISTINCT(nro_ticket)'));
```

can you help me?

Comment: not clear, can u post some examples.

Comment: I have two columns, and if exists a value in one of the two columns I would like to count it.. all that I want to do is a count of the two columns

Comment: what about two column with different values,like `1, 2` and another record has `1,3`, count as one or two?

Comment: I did a count of a single column with this:

$ttg = DB::table('incidencias')
        ->where('inc_padre', '!=', '') 
        ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT(inc_padre)'));

Comment: the values dont have to be the same in the two columns, but if I have in the same column a value repeated I would not like to count it, because is repeated, only I would like to count it one time

Comment: so you want to count two columns, and the result is two numbers ?

Comment: no... if in one of the two columns exist a value I would like to add a number to the count.. all in the same count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` to concat two columns, and add a separator like `:` (choose the unique separator you need),

and `group by` this concat columns:

```php
$individuales = DB::table('incidencias')
                  ->where(function($q) {
                      $q->where('inc_padre', '!=', '')->whereNotNull('inc_padre');
                  })
                  ->orWhere(function($q) { 
                      $q->where('nro_ticket', '!=', '')->whereNotNull('nro_ticket');
                  })
                  ->groupBy(DB::raw("CONCAT(IFNULL(inc_padre,''), ':', IFNULL(nro_ticket,''))"))                
                  ->selectRaw("COUNT(CONCAT(IFNULL(inc_padre,''), ':', IFNULL(nro_ticket,''))) AS count, CONCAT(IFNULL(inc_padre,''), ':', IFNULL(nro_ticket,'')) AS two_columns")
                  ->count();
```

Comment: @Oscar you forget the comma in `->orWhere('nro_ticket', '!=', '') ` in the post...

Comment: yes, but is the same.. i got this error syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: it gave me only a number 1

Comment: @Oscar the number is the count, you can use `get` instead of `count` to see the repeat count in group. and what's the type of these two columns?

Comment: I have two columns, in some records I have varchar and the other records are empty, I want to count the number of records that have information but some records are repeated and I want to take them in the same count... I have 152 rows so if in one of the tow colums it exist a record should be added a number to the count

Comment: For example tow columns with 152 rows if exists a record in one of the to columns in the row should add a number to the count but if I have a record repeated in the column dont have to be counted

Comment: I dont have null values in my database, only empty records

Comment: the same, it gave me only a number 1